# chrome extension: createImageData IndexSizeError but code still works

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension.

The default popup has a button, and that button's click eventlistener calls a script. The code is below.

It creates a canvas element, appends it to the body element, and draws a circle which moves across the page. It works.

```
(function() {

  let b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  let c = document.createElement('canvas');
  b.appendChild(c);

  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
  c.style.position = 'fixed';
  c.style.top = '0';
  c.style.left = '0';

  let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  let imgdata = ctx.createImageData(c.width, c.height);

  let frameCount = 0;
  let draw = setInterval(function() {
    frameCount += 1;
    ctx.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);

    ctx.fillStyle = '#fc0c';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(300+frameCount, 300, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

  }, 20);

})();
```

My thinking was to create a blank `imagedata` element the same size as the canvas, and 'paint' it onto the canvas every frame to reset the canvas for the coming frame. In this way, the ball will look like it is moving over top of the rest of the elements of the page.

In fact, this is what the code above does. But there is something that is nagging me.

**The problem**

In `chrome://extensions/` I'm seeing an error. The error is the `IndexSizeError` which you get when you pass a `0` value to `createImageData`. But, while I'm receiving this error, the `imagedata` element is still being created, and if I print it to the console I know it is being created in the way I expect.

Going slightly deeper, `Inspect views background page` reports the same thing.

Anyhow, this code is executed once you click the button on the main extension popup, and so `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` are already available.

I even used promises to ensure `ctx` and `imgdata` were not assigned values until `c.width` and `c.height` were set. Running out of ideas, I also tried using `setTimeout` and I'm getting the same error. The end result was identical to what I get now, which is that the animation works exactly as I expect.

**The concern**

While I am achieving the result I want, I am eager to discover the cause of this error message. I'm not sure if it is reporting something that I have done wrong, which may impact my little project somewhere down the line.

**Update: including the json manifest**

The file which contains the code above is `file.js`

```
{
 "name": "Name",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "Very description",
 "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js", "file.js"],
    "persistent": false
 },
 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["otherfile.js"]
 }],
 "options_page": "",
 "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
     "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/1.png",
        "32": "images/2.png",
        "48": "images/3.png",
        "128": "images/4.png"
     }
 },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/1.png",
        "32": "images/2.png",
        "48": "images/2.png",
        "128": "images/4.png"
    },
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "web_accessible_resources": ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", "images/4.png"]
}
```

Comment: That list shows outdated errors (there's a button to clear it inside) so you need to use the actual devtools. Right-click inside the popup, click "inspect", then debug the code.

Comment: It's unclear why you see this error in a totally unrelated background script so it's possible your manifest.json is wrong, for example you're loading the same popup.js both in the popup page and in the background page.

Comment: I'm still new to extensions but the error is showing up in 'chrome://extensions' page for managing extensions. I can clear the error, but it keeps popping up again. Clearing or not clearing does not change the result - it does work either way. The context of that error is '_generated_background_page.html' and it does refer to the .js file containing the script I wrote above. I'll review the manifest.

Comment: Are you running this `ctx.createImageData(c.width, c.height);` in background js file?

Comment: @dactyrafficle, make sure to always include manifest.json entirely so we don't have to guess and suggest irrelevant things to try.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I've updated it to include the manifest.json

Comment: I removed 'file.js' from the background property of the manifest, and that error is no longer appearing.